# Algorithm sometimes works

Tags: java, arrays

I am currently trying to set up a sorting algorithm for an array that scans for the highest and lowest number and places them into a new array, two at a time. I've noticed that it appears to work only in certain conditions. For example, I can input it as {5, 3, 10, 7} or {3, 5, 10, 7}, but {7, 3, 5, 10} produces an IndexOutOfBoundsException: index 1, size: 1;

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; // program uses class Scanner
import java.util.ArrayList; //helps with arrays

public class ArrayAlg
{
// main method begins execution of Java application
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    // create a Scanner to obtain input from the command window
    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

    boolean AS = false; //array sorted.

    int hi     =   0; //high number
    int low    = 100; //set to 100 for logic reasons.
    int oldhi  =   0;
    int oldlow =   0;
    int NI     =   0;
    int addA   =   0;
    int p      =   0; //places, moves right after one scan to place the next int
    int n      =   1; //number of times, moves left after one to place the next int

    String cont = "n";

    ArrayList<Integer> IParray = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //input array
    ArrayList<Integer> Sarray = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //sorted array

    while (cont.equals("n"))
    {
        System.out.print("Please enter a number for the array: ");
        addA = input.nextInt();
        IParray.add(addA);
        NI++;
        System.out.print("\n is that all? (y/n): ");
        cont = input.next();
    }

    for (int c = 0; c < NI; c++) //adds 0 so sorting will be easier
        Sarray.add(0); //matches the inputted array

    System.out.print("The inputted array: ");
    System.out.print(IParray);
    System.out.println("");

    while (AS == false){

        hi = 0;
        low = 100;

        for (int i = 0; i < IParray.size(); i++)
        {

            if (IParray.get(i) < low)
                low = IParray.get(i);

            if (IParray.get(i) > hi)
            {
                //if (IParray.get(i) > hi) currently commented out, doesn't effect the logic by the looks of it.
                    hi = IParray.get(i);
            }

        }//end for

        Sarray.set(p, low); //sets the number in the left most position then moves to the right
        Sarray.set(Sarray.size() - n, hi); //sets the number to the rightmost position and moves left

        p++; //increase place count to the right
        n++; //increases the place count to the left

        oldhi = IParray.indexOf(hi); //oldhi becomes the index of the recent highest number.
        oldlow = IParray.indexOf(low); //oldlow becomes the index of the recent lowest number
        IParray.remove(oldhi); //removes the highest number at the index
        IParray.remove(oldlow); //removes the lowest number at the index, exceptions occurs right here.

        System.out.print("The inputted array: ");//mostly here to see what the inputted array looks like after one iteration
        System.out.print(IParray);
        System.out.println("");


        System.out.print("The sorted array: ");
        System.out.print(Sarray);
        System.out.println("");

        if (IParray.isEmpty() == true) //checks to see if the input array is empty
            AS = true;
        else
            AS = false;

    }//end while


} // end method main

} // end class ArrayAlg
```

Can anyone give me any hints on why this might be occurring? I've been trying this out for the past hour or so. Tried Googling and searching this site for answers but no luck

Comment: what line produces the exception?

Comment: does the exception occur with an even amount of numbers in the array, or only with an odd amount?

Comment: K_g: line 73.  David, both with even and odd. Paul: n and p sets the hi and low numbers in the array at a certain index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the index out of bounds because it is trying to remove an index that does not exist. When it is removing indexes it removes lowest first causing the whole array index to shift downwards. It does not keep it's original index.

```
[0] =  7
[1] = 3
[2] = 5
[3] = 10
```

When removing the high number, 10, it becomes:

```
[0] =  7
[1] = 3
[2] = 5
```

When removing the low number it becomes:

```
[0] =  7
[1] = 5
```

The next loop you remove 7 first leaving only 5 at index 0 but your code is calling to remove index 1 giving you an out of bounds exception.

To fix this, let it dynamically get the index when the remove method is called.

```
 IParray.remove(IParray.indexOf(hi)); //removes the highest number at the index
 IParray.remove(IParray.indexOf(low)); //removes the lowest number at the index
```

You should have been able to quickly find this error by running your code in debugging mode and then stepping through the code that is throwing the exception (Line 73).

Comment: Now I see, now I got it working, I set the already used numbers to -1 and the sorting algorithm to not include those numbers when scanning, thank you. Now to fix the exit conditions

Comment: You are welcome. Debugging makes it very easy to spot these kinds of errors. I strongly suggest stepping through code that is having an issue and watch your arrays and variables change.

Answer (score 0):

You might not be able to find a higher value and lower value comparison to previous ones. For example, input array was `{7, 3, 5, 10}`, now `hi` is 10 and `low` is 7, they were removed from `IParray`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < IParray.size(); i++)
{
    if (IParray.get(i) < low)
        low = IParray.get(i);  // low becomes 3 

    if (IParray.get(i) > hi) //!!! never able to find a higher value than 10 !!!
    {
        //if (IParray.get(i) > hi) currently commented out, doesn't effect the logic by the looks of it.
            hi = IParray.get(i);  
    }
}
```

In that case, `low` and `high` points to previous values, which was removed from the array since last iteration, so `oldhi` and `oldlow` would be -1, and you got the exception for `IParray.remove(-1)`

```
oldhi = IParray.indexOf(hi); // 10 is not in the array anymore, you got -1
oldlow = IParray.indexOf(low); 
IParray.remove(oldhi); // you got exception here as you remove(-1)
IParray.remove(oldlow);
```

Comment: I reset the values to low = 100; and hi = 0; at the beginning of the while so that way they wouldn't be pointing to previous values if the loop continued.